# Mongodb REST API returns no results

Tags: mongodb, rest, nginx

I'm using the builtin MongoDB ["simple REST interface"](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-interface) to try to tie together my MongoDB collection with a simple javascript frontend without writing an API myself. I have the REST server up and running, as proven by running the following inside my production server:

```
$> http get "http://localhost:28017/mydb/mycoll/?limit=1"
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 437
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
x-action:
x-ns: mydb.mycoll

{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { <redacted data> }
  ],
  "total_rows" : 1 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

The Mongodb REST server does not by, by default, bind to an interface which is publicly accessible, so I'm proxying localhost:28017 to the outside world using Nginx, with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name api.myapp.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen              443 default_server;
    server_name         api.myapp.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/myapp.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp.key;

    access_log /logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /logs/nginx_error.log;

    location /mongo {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:28017;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I reload nginx and try the same query I ran inside the machine hosting Mongo from a machine outside that network instead, and get:

```
$> http get "https://api.myapp.com/mongo/mydb/mycoll/?limit=1"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 27 Feb 2015 17:06:40 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-action:
x-ns: mongo.mydb.mycoll

{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [

  ],

  "total_rows" : 0 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

Essentially, it *is* hitting the Mongo REST server (making it through the nginx proxy), but it is not returning any results for the same query that I ran on localhost.

The only lead I have so far is that the `x-ns` header on the two responses is different - like the Mongo REST server is not picking up the fact that Nginx is instructing it to lie behind the `https://api.myapp.com/mongo` route and is instead thinking I'm trying to access the database `mongo`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't recommend the rest interface. It's not well-supported and may be deprecated soon. Use a driver. You don't want a production system running through the REST interface.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually ended up using [RESTHeart](http://restheart.org/) because the built-in server did not support complex queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue. The problem was as I guessed at the end of my question: the Nginx config was proxying requests to the Mongo API server with the `/mongo/` path intact, resulting in queries being run on the (nonexistent) database `mongo`.

I fixed the problem by adding the following line to the `/mongo/` location in the Nginx configuration file:

```
rewrite /mongo/(.+) /$1 break;
```

so that it reads, in full:

```
location /mongo/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite /mongo/(.+) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:28017;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who gave this question a look.